# AJax call does not work with anchor tag link button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using Jquery with MVC
I am having some problem with onclick event of anchor tag.
This is calling a Javascript function which in turn is giving an AJAX call to controller

```
 <a id="LoginLink_@Model.DomainLibraries[i].Id" href=""  onclick="LoginLibrary(this);" domainLibId="130" HasRole="false" style="text-decoration:underline;">Login</a>

    function LoginLibrary(obj) {
        var selectedLibraryId = obj.getAttribute('domainLibId');
        var hasUserRole = obj.getAttribute('HasRole');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Account/LoginLibrary",
            data: { domainLibraryId: selectedLibraryId, hasUserRole: hasUserRole },
            success: function (arg) {
                alert(arg);
                $("#divExAuthLibSetting").html(arg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

What is happening is, WHen I click on Login link, before call goes to controller method, it is giving an alert with an empty value maybe because "alert(arg);". Then the call goes to controller. But after response from controller, I am not able to get anything in arg.

The thing us if I call function LoginLibrary() in document.Ready(), it is working fine.
I am able to get the response 'arg' and show it in div.

Does it mean that ajax call does not work with anchor tag on click..

Comment: This looks like a job fooor: *someone else*!

Comment: You are using jQuery, yet you are using `onclick="LoginLibrary(this);"` in HTML? There's a long way ahead of you, young padawan. ;)

Comment: `alert(arg)` won't fire until ajax data is sent back which is what triggers the `success` callback so issue doen't make sense unless nothing is being returned. Inspect request in browser console to see what is being sent and what is being returned

Comment: Does the controller return the right data? (Check with Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools)

Comment: Well.. I tried with <label> tag onclick event of <label>.. And it worked perfectly fine. I dont know what it is , but it just doesn not work with <a> anchor tag